# Building a list of types used for the function

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang

Assuming I have a function in the following form,

```
template<typename T>
int some_call(T t){
  return t;
}
```

Is is possible to in compile time build a list of `typenames` and find the largest `T` used. i.e,

```
  some_call(int(42));
  some_call(long(42));
```

I would like to find `sizeof(long)` since it is largest size used. The reason I am trying to do is I will allocate an array to hold some memory for a calculation I would like to allocate big enough to hold largest type.

Comment: Due to how templates work, `some_call<int>` and `some_call<long>` are two ***different*** functions. So they could use their own separate buffer for whatever calculations they need (preferably in the form of a `std::vector<T>`).

Comment: The best I can imagine is set a dimension and check, compile-time through a `static_assert()` inside the template function, that `sizeof(T) <= fixed_size`. This doesn't set the minimal size required but, compile time, give you assurance that the size if sufficient.

Comment: sounds stateful

Comment: Are you going to be calling this function with a bunch of different types but want to store all the returns in a single vector/array?  If that is the cast `std::ptrdiff_t` should be okay unless you are using the 64th bit of 64 bit numbers.  Could you show how you would be using it?

Comment: @NathanOliver All processing will be done once in compile time result of size of i will use it to initilize a stack `allocator allocator<page_size>`

Comment: Or if you're sharing some memory between *all* different instances of the `some_call` template, then perhaps use `intmax_t` which is the standard maximum width integer type.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Example involse `int / long` to keep it short actual types in use will be custom non pod types.

Comment: Them the answer is "no". You can't get the max size from the compiler inside the source. Not unless you have an extra pre-processing utility which extracts that information and provides it in some form to the source. And you should really edit your question with that information, since it's kind of crucial.